# Finding all patterns in a string in python- findall and finditer dont work

Tags: python, regex, findall

lets say i have a string `s = <html><head1><title>something1something2<html><head2><title1>somethings1<html><head3><title1>somethings2<html><head3><title>somethings3`

i'm looking for a `pattern = '<html><.*?><title>'`, my string has 2 types of pattern, `'<html><.*?><title>'` and `'<html><.*?><title1>'` and i want to list all the substrings matching the first pattern
when i use findall or finditer, what i get is 
`<html><head1><title>` and

```
<html><head2><title1>somethings1<html><head3><title1>somethings2<html><head3><title>
```

But what i want to get is

```
<html><head1><title> 
<html><head3><title>
```

or ideally, head1, head3

My code below,

```
s = <html><head1><title>something1something2<html><head2><title1>somethings1<html><head3><title1>somethings2<html><head3><title>somethings3
result = re.finditer('<html><.*?><title>', s)
```

or

```
print re.findall('<html><.*?><title>', s)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to find within the string...

Comment: The regex engine is giving you exactly what you asked for. Those *are* the matches for `<html><.*?><title>`. Also, you need to use code formatting for HTML markup, or it'll get interpreted as you trying to apply that markup to your post instead of you wanting that text to literally appear in your post.

Comment: This is my first time posting a question on stack overflow and did not realize that i need to tag the code in my text, say for some reason i do not want to use the usual web page parsing module like beautiful soup for this task. i want to be able to do it with the re module or any generic pattern matching module in python

Comment: Pattern matching algorithms just don't understand the nested state of a HTML or XML document. You need an HTML or XML parser to do it correctly.